# GridView Scroll By one row

Tags: android, gridview, custom-scrolling

Hi i am implementing a gridView and i have trouble making it scroll down 1 row at a time with every scroll event.

my grid has a height of 1 row item (items height is 75dp). i don't want scrolling to be left in a middle of a row.

is there a way i can intercept and modify the scroll distance so that it only returns fixed value ex: +-75dp.

i would appreciate any help or suggestions you can give me. tnx

Answer (score 2):

APIv8 has new function, called smoothScrollBy(int distance, int duration)[1]

i think you should catch all scroll events & implement own method to scroll view.
if you want to scroll by 75dp, just convert it to pixels & use function above.

```
float density = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int scrollBy = (int)(density * 75);
smoothScrollBy(scrollBy, 0);
```

But would be nice to calculate scrollBy from your GridView, instead of using some constant value (like 75dp)

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollBy(int, int)

Comment: some months ago i searched for a solution to scroll GridView programmatically for APIv7, but unfortunately didn't find...

Comment: did you ever happen to find the answer to this?